# Сравнение содержимого выпадающих списков

Tags: java, android

Мне нужен пример кода как сравнить содержимое двух спиенеров, т.е. если у третьего спиннера выбрано тоже самое, что и у двух других, то вывести текст

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У `Spinner` есть метод `getSelectedItemPosition()`, который вернет позицию выбранного элемента. При помощи этого метода, вы можете достать из адаптера выбранный элемент, и после этого - сравнить два объекта между собой